# Full Screen Grid View

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

i have gridview in my windwos store app and i want this gridview to fill whole screen - to have 100% width and height. 
This is my gridview in xaml:

```
<GridView x:Name="ItmLView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="751" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1361" SelectionChanged="FeedItemClick" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"/>
```

Can anybody help me please?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove properties affecting size and position, like, Height, Margin, Width, etc. and have it like this:

```
<GridView x:Name="ItmLView" SelectionChanged="FeedItemClick" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"/>
```

Basically, we just want GridView to have HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" and VerticalAlignment="Stretch" which are the default values, so you don't need to put anything.